# Using Pytorch model trained on RTX2080 on RTX3060

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I try to run my PyTorch model (trained on a Nvidia RTX2080) on the newer Nvidia RTX3060 with CUDA support. It is possible to load the model and to execute it. If I run it on the CPU with the `--no_cuda` flag it runs smootly and gives back the correct predictions, but if I want to run it with CUDA, it only returns wrong predictions which make no sense.
Does the different GPU-architecture of the cards affect the prediction?

Comment: Could you share some code? Also what is the expected result and what are you seeing from the GPU execution?

Comment: Could just be a bug in the eval code, like `if torch.cuda.is_available: do_the_buggy_code()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it seemed that the problem was the different floating point of the two architectures. The flag `torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32 = false` needs to be set, to provide a stable execution of the model of a different architecture.